# Mongoose Schema: Forcing an array of objects to be created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  fbid       : String,
  googleid   : String,
  birthday   : String,
  email      : String,
  first_name : String,
  last_name  : String,
  gender     : String,
  age        : Number,
  location   : String,
  paid       : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
  lessons: [
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar1'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar2'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar3'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar4'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar5'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar6'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar7'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    },
    { 
      name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar8'},
      sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
      activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
    } 
  ]

});
```

When doing `new User()`, everything is created properly *except* for the `lessons` array, which returns as an empty array rather than creating the nested objects with their default values.

It is possible to make these objects when doing `new User()`, but I want this to occur in the model itself as all users will have the same `lessons` and same initial values.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: it should be `new mongoose.Schema(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following link would be helpful for setting default values for nested Array in mongoose Schema.

[set default values to mongoose arrays in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861417/set-default-values-to-mongoose-arrays-in-node-js)

You could do like this:

```
var lessonSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    sent: { type: Boolean },
    read: { type: Boolean },
    activity: { type: Boolean }
});

var userSchema = Schema({
    fbid: { type: String },
    googleid: { type: String },
    birthday: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    age: { type: Number },
    location: { type: String },
    paid: { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
    lessons: [lessonSchema]
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (!this.lessons || this.lessons.length == 0) {
        this.lessons = [];
        this.lessons.push({
            "name": "football 1",
            "sent": true,
            "read": true,
            "activity": true
        })

         this.lessons.push({
            "name": "football 2",
            "sent": true,
            "read": true,
            "activity": true
        })

         this.lessons.push({
            "name": "football 3",
            "sent": true,
            "read": true,
            "activity": true
        })

         this.lessons.push({
            "name": "football 3",
            "sent": true,
            "read": true,
            "activity": true
        })
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a pre save hook in your schema

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    this.set('lessons', [ ... ]);
  }
  next();
});
```

More info here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

Set default value in your schema declaration:

```
var defaultLessons = [
    { 
      name    : 'foobar1',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar2',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar3',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar4',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar5',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar6',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar7',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    ,
    { 
      name    : 'foobar8',
      sent    : 0 ,
      read    : 0 ,
      activity: 0 
    } 
  ];

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  lessons: { type: [], default: defaultLessons}
});
```

Another more structure way is to use [sub docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```
var lessonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({                                                                         
  name    : { type: String,  default: 'foobar'},
  sent    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
  read    : { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
  activity: { type: Boolean, default: 0 }
});

var defaultLessons = [ 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar1', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar2', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar3', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar4', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar5', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar6', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar7', 
    }, 
    {  
      name    : 'foobar8', 
    }  
  ];

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  lessons: { type: [lessonSchema], default: defaultLessons}
});
```

However, above does not work in mongoose 4+, I've tried mongoose 3.8 ok. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092479/mongoose-schema-embedded-document-default).